# Match a subdirectory path with Spring Web MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following code, but the only reason for the second method to exist is because the first method isn't matching sub-directories of static files I'm serving.

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{filename:.+}" )
public ResponseEntity<?> getFile( @PathVariable final String filename ) {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource( root.resolve( filename ).toUri().toString() );
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .cacheControl( CacheControl.maxAge( 1, TimeUnit.DAYS ).proxyRevalidate().cachePrivate() )
            .body( resource );
}

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{path}/{filename:.+}" )
public ResponseEntity<?> getFile( @PathVariable final String path, @PathVariable  final String filename ) {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource( root.resolve( path ).resolve( filename ).toUri().toString() );
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .cacheControl( CacheControl.maxAge( 1, TimeUnit.DAYS ).proxyRevalidate().cachePrivate() )
            .body( resource );
}
```